# How to catch or receive android os ' broadcasts' of installed applications?

Tags: android

I want to receive broadcasts of android installed applications. What would be the procedure ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can register Broadcast intent `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` ( and/or `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`, `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED` if needed).

Code is something like following:

```
void registerReceiver() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
    filter.addDataScheme("package");
    ...
}

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String actionStr = intent.getAction();
    if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED.equals(actionStr)) {
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        String pkgName = data.getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart();
        //handle package adding...
    ...
    }
}
```