# Detect if application is installing

Tags: android, installation, package

I know that you can check if an application is installed, and that Android has an intent for when the application installation completed.

Is it possible to check if one package is under installation?

I'm developing a installer and I'm using the bellow code to start the installation proccess

```
Uri apkFile = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/myDownloaded.apk")); 

Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
promptInstall.setDataAndType(apkFile, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes can be notified when other apps are installed: [How to catch or receive android os ' broadcasts' of installed applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717067/how-to-catch-or-receive-android-os-broadcasts-of-installed-applications)