# Detect install ending in Android

Tags: android, installation, apk

I want to make a simple Android App that will download another app, install it and after that delete the downloaded file. I read on the internet that you can launch the install rather easy: [Detect if application is installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737651/detect-if-application-is-installing)
The think is I could not find how to detect if the install finished (or has returned an error). If anyone know how to detect installation ending please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a `BroadcastReceiver` with an intent filter for [Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)

Comment: Thanks, That worked really well :) There still are a few minor tweeks that need to be done but you put me on the right track.

Comment: Great. I wasn't 100% sure if it was what you wanted but thought it was worth looking at. Glad to help.