# Android: detetct app after installation

Tags: android, installation, detect

I am downloading an Android app from a server and installing it. I want to detect when the installation is completed. I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717067/how-to-catch-or-receive-android-os-broadcasts-of-installed-applications) but it didn't work. Is there any other example?

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your manifest:

```
<manifest>
    ....
    <application>
        ....
        <receiver android:name=".YourReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED">
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Then, create a `YourReceiver`class and put in the following:

```
public class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

final static String TAG = "YourReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Intent received!");

    Uri data = intent.getData();
    String pkgName = data.getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart();

    if (pkgName.equals("some.app.name")) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Package installed");
    }


}
```

}